# How to redirect from one subfolder to a subsubfolder with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, mod-alias

I have this folder structure:

```
/fonts
  /myfont.eot
  /myfont.svg
  /myfont.ttf
  /myfont.woff
  /myfont.woff2
/content
  /page1
    /files
      /logo.png
      /style.css
    /index.html
  /page2
    /files
      /logo.png
      /style.css
    /index.html
  /page3
    /files
      /logo.png
      /style.css
    /a
      /index.html
    /b
      /index.html
  ...
```

The URLs one would call look like this:

- `example.com/content/page1`
- `example.com/content/page2`
- `example.com/content/page3/a`
- `example.com/content/page3/b`

Now all I want to achieve with an `.htaccess` file located in `/page3` is that whoever visits `example.com/content/page3` is properly redirect to `example.com/content/page3/a` (or `example.com/content/page3/a/index.html`, I don't mind whether the file name is in the URL or not).

I tried

```
DirectoryIndex /content/page3/a/index.html
```

but in this case when I open `example.com/content/page3` all relative references in the `/a/index.html` file are broken because of the missing directory level in the URL. Furthermore, while calling `example.com/content/page3/a` works, `example.com/content/page3/b` gives 403 Forbidden.

I tried

```
Redirect 301 /content/page3 /content/page3/a
```

but this obviously results in an endless redirect spiral to `example.com/content/page3/a/a/a/a/a/a/......` until the server stops trying.

So I figured I need some `RedirectCond` and `RedirectRule` configuration. Unfortunately, I don't understand the syntax, and all examples I looked at are doing it on the top-level with more complex stuff like redirecting files and sub-folders, sometimes off to another domain etc.

I tried this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/content/page3/$
RewriteRule ^/content/page3/?$ /content/page3/a [L]
```

because I figured this would replace "/content/page3" with "/content/page3/a", but to no avail, it doesn't do anything.

I now went with using

```
DirectoryIndex /content/page3/a/index.html index.html
```

and replaced the relative references in the document with absolute ones. This works.

But firstly I would still prefer if the references could remain relative, so the document doesn't break in case the `page3` folder is ever renamed, and secondly I'd rather have the `/a` subdirectory in the URL for clarity as to what is displayed.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> I would still prefer if the references could remain relative

In that case you really need an *external redirect*, not an internal rewrite or internal subrequest (which is what you are essentially doing with the `DirectoryIndex` directive). And if you'd "rather have the `/a` subdirectory in the URL" then you definitely need an external redirect.

> The URLs one would call look like this:
>
> - `example.com/content/page1`
> - `example.com/content/page2`
> - `example.com/content/page3/a`
> - `example.com/content/page3/b`

I note that you've not included trailing slashes on any of these URLs that map to physical directories. These should contain trailing slashes for what you are trying to do i.e. link to `example.com/content/page1/`, not `example.com/content/page1`. The reason being is that Apache (mod_dir) will otherwise "fix" the URL with a 301 redirect to append the trailing slash. If you do want to omit the trailing slash on these "directory" URLs then you have more work to do.

> an `.htaccess` file located in `/page3`

Using mod_rewrite you could do the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /content/page3/a/ [R,L]
```

This is a temporary (302) redirect. `^$` matches an empty URL-path. It is "empty" because it is relative to the current directory. mod_dir will then issue the subrequest for the `DirectoryIndex`, i.e. `index.html`.

Alternatively, use mod_alias `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/content/page3/?$ /content/page3/a/
```

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/content/page3/?$ /content/page3/a [L]
> ```

This would never work because in a directory context (i.e. `.htaccess`) the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash.

If you wrote this in the root `.htaccess` file, it should read:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^content/page3/?$ /content/page3/a/ [R,L]
```

The two preceding conditions are not required - unless you have multiple domains?

The corresponding mod_alias directive would be the same as above (regardless of where the `.htaccess` file is located).

---

The `DirectoryIndex` should simply be set to:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

In order to serve the `index.html` document out of the requested directory.

---

> ```
> Redirect 301 /content/page3 /content/page3/a
> ```

This will create a redirect loop because the mod_alias `Redirect` directive is *prefix* matching, and everything after the match is appended onto the target URL i.e. The redirected URL `/content/page3/a` matches the source URL `/content/page3` and `/a` is appended onto the end of the target (`/content/page3/a`) to become `/content/page3/a/a` etc.

Note that 301 (permanent) redirects are cached persistently by the browser. You will need to clear your browser cache. Always test with 302 (temporary) redirects and only change to 301 (permanent) - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed that it works OK.

Comment: Thank you so far. I've read your reply and am still trying to wrap my head around all the stuff you wrote. I don't know what that "mod_rewrite" is exactly, but I think it's maybe a server module? In this it should be installed by my hoster because the `Rewrite###` configs did have an effect for other stuff I tried (but it produced really messy paths including the server-internal directories etc.) Maybe the problem is me not realizing the whole patterns are relative to the directory, maybe that's the point I was missing. I will test around a bit, thanks!

Comment: On the path: I don't mind at all if the server adds the trailing slash. It's not so much about cosmetics of the URL, more about consistency. When you see content a, the path should ideally contain the `/a` part. If that's `/a` or `/a/`or `/a/index.html` is not that important.

Comment: Yes, mod_rewrite is Apache's URL rewriting module (which also does _redirects_). `RewriteRule` (and `RewriteCond`) are part of mod_rewrite. mod_rewrite is very powerful, but with that power comes additional complexity. Whereas `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` are part of mod_alias. `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` are for "simple" redirects only. You should avoid mixing rewrites/redirects from both modules as you can get unexpected conflicts due to way different modules are executed.

Comment: "I don't mind at all if the server adds the trailing slash." - But if you let the server do this then you end up with an undesirable additional redirect. Which is why you should always include the trailing slash on these URLs that map directory to a physical directory. (If these URLs did not map to the file system then personally I avoid the trailing slash - but that is not the case here.) It is generally preferred to  avoid having `index.html` (the `DirectoryIndex`) in the URL - it is unnecessary and just adds complexity to the "visible" URL.

Comment: I don't mind what the "visible URL" is, so if the trailing slash ends up being there that's okay. But I cannot guarantee people will put it there when visiting my site, so it has to work for both cases. That's what I intended to say. Sorry if that was unclear. "you end up with an undesirable additional redirect" - what's the problem with that? Is one automated and one configured redirect in combination bad?

Comment: "so if the trailing slash ends up being there that's okay" - regardless of what the user _types_ (users rarely _type_ URLs anyway), you just need to make sure you always link to the canonical URL with the trailing slash, otherwise, every time the user clicks a link on your site, they will potentially experience an additional redirect (two HTTP requests to your server, slower for the users, confusing for bots, loss of POST data in form submissions, etc.)